CentOs: Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user
Problem
When installing a package with:
sudo yum install ncdu -y

I encountered this error:
[Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user."

Solution
To fix this, you can temporarily disable SSL verification.
Warning: Disabling SSL verification bypasses security measures and is not recommended for regular use.

Open the yum configuration file with:
sudo vi /etc/yum.conf


Add the following line to the file:
sslverify=0


Save and exit the editor.

Now, retry the package installation:
sudo yum install ncdu -y

Note
After installing the package, it is strongly recommended to remove or comment out the sslverify=0 line to re-enable SSL verification and maintain system security.
